# Get detailed error information on creating httpwebrequest from c# to website

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, system.net.webexception

I am checking a website is active or not using below code. If website is inactive like screen shot. I want to log the detailed error information from the response. how can i do it..? please suggest.. [image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
    private static bool CheckWebSiteActive()
    {
        bool isWebSiteActive = false;
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = null;
            Stream resst = null;
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webSiteToCheck"]);
            request.Timeout = 10000;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // find out if this site is up and don't follow a redirector
            request.Method = "HEAD";

            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                using (WebResponse Wresponse = we.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)Wresponse;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    using (Stream data = Wresponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                }
                //response = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
                //resst = response.GetResponseStream();
                //sr = new StreamReader(resst);
                log.Error(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
            isWebSiteActive = ((int)response.StatusCode == 200 && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) ? true : false;

        }catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            log.Error(Ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        return isWebSiteActive;
    }
```

Thanks in adv.

Comment: I suppose the error is in your Web.config file. Is there any duplicate key?

Comment: Yes, there will be a duplicate key. When there is duplicate key i want to display/log the duplicate key information to user. Or any other Exception i want to display/log the "Detailed Error Information"(Marked in green) to user. How can i do it..